# Can someone explain what a Function object is in Java?

Tags: java, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with understanding a function object or functor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369460/help-with-understanding-a-function-object-or-functor-in-java)

I am currently reading the book "data structures and problem solving using Java" by Mark Allen Weiss and the explanation of a functor is not clear to me.

1) Why do you use them?
2) Exactly what do they do?

The only thing I am getting from this book is if a particular object does not have a compareTo method you use a function object to give it one ha-ha.....help me!!

Answer (score 2):

Functors encapsulate functions as objects.  You can pass them around to other objects to get things done.

Think [Gang of Four Command Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command).

Answer (score 0):

If an object does not implement `Comparable` you can write an implementation of [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to achieve the same effect. `Comparator` is, in fact, the example given in the wikipedia arctile about [functors in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_Java). If the an object is not `Comparable` it can still be sorted by `Collections.sort(Collection, Comparator)` by providing a relevant `Comparator` implementation.

The interface `Comparator` is an example of a functor. Implementations of it can be passed around for other objects or methods to use to do something (In this case compare two objects).