# How to get Child class?

Tags: java

I want to create an  object of child class

more than 100 class extend MasterClass

MasterClass is

```
 public class MasterClass{
  int key;
  String value;
  String displayValue;
  boolean status;
 } 
 public class User extends MasterClass{
 public User(){ }
 }
 public class Customer extends MasterClass{
 String productName;
 public Customer (){ }
 }
```

etc...

i will get a MasterClass object from client, i wanted to type cast that object to respective one

```
if(masterClass instanceof User) {  
  User a_user = (User) a_ masterClass;
  …
} else if(masterClass instanceof Customer) {
  Customer a_customer = (Customer) a_ masterClass;
  …
}
```

if i do this i will end up with 100s of else if.

Please let me know how i can achieve this without else if?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just advice : read http://stackoverflow.com/help to put readable questions

Comment: Please really think about your design if you have a type hierarchy where `User` and `Customer` extend a `MasterClass`. What is it that `MasterClass` gives you which you could not solve more elegant by composition?

Comment: What do you intend to do with each casted reference (`a_user`, etc)? Without knowing much more, my hunch is that polymorphism can do it by just having a method on `MasterClass`.

Comment: @Matthias As your replay i have change the code please check it. do the help need full

Answer (score 3):

Use polymorphism and generics, as Java intended.

Polymorphism lets you call a method on your object that behaves differently for every type. The easiest way to achieve this is to provide an abstract method in the base class `MasterClass` and then override it with different functionality in every extended class. You are probably looking for something like this:

```
class MasterClass {
    int age;
    // ...
    public abstract void doWork();
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    // .. more methods
}

class User extends MasterClass {
    // customize User here
    @Override
    public void doWork() {  /* User does work in some way */ }
}

class Customer extends MasterClass {
    // customize Customer here
    @Override
    public void doWork() {  /* Customer does work in some other way */ }
}

// ...
```

If you are not too familiar with [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) is a good introductory tutorial.

If you are not allowed to alter your classes, you can populate a look-up table like `HashMap<Class, MyFunctor>` where you can assign a different [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369460/help-with-understanding-a-function-object-or-functor-in-java) for every type of person you have.

Also, you might want to use [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). Generics allow you to capture and restrict the type of objects passed to your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use generics with the constraint T extends MasterClass?

Answer (score 0):

Using basic concepts of Design Pattern you can create a constructor like this in the object where you try to initialize

```
MasterClass masterClass;

public MyCreatorOject(MasterClass masterClass)
{
    this.masterClass = masterClass;
}
```

later when you create the object it can be

```
new MyCreatorObject(new User());
```

or

```
new MyCreatorObject(new Customer());
```