# How to wrap a java.lang.Appendable into a java.io.Writer?

Tags: java, io, writer

UPDATE2: My own version of the adapter class, that only calls `instanceof` in the constructor and uses a (Java 1.5) delta in the `flush()` and `close()` functions (avoiding the need for any reflection or logic after object construction), is included at the bottom of this post. UPDATE1: Marc Baumbach wrote a simple Adapter that is exactly what I need. Included below. Original question follows.

---

A function that requires a [`java.lang.Appendable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) can accept a [`java.io.Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html), because `Writer` implements `Appendable`.

What about the other way around? I am using a function that requires a writer, and I am trying to create another function that calls it, which accepts an appendable and passes it to the original writer-function.

I see that you can extend `Writer`, which is abstract, and redirect all `write(...)` functions to their corresponding `append(...)`-s. But you also have to implement [`flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush%28%29) and [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close%28%29), and I'm clear on how to write those cleanly so this wrapper-class can accept *any* Appendable.

I'm surprised there isn't anything already out there, either on the web or stackoverflow, or in an existing library, that addresses this. At least not that I could find.

I'd appreciate a little guidance here. Thank you.

---

Adapter code that answers this question. Written by Marc Baumbach (my own version is below):

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.Flushable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

public class AppendableWriterAdapter extends Writer {

      private Appendable appendable;

      public AppendableWriterAdapter(Appendable appendable) {
            this.appendable = appendable;
      }

      @Override
      public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            appendable.append(String.valueOf(cbuf), off, len);
      }

      @Override
      public void flush() throws IOException {
            if (appendable instanceof Flushable) {
                  ((Flushable) appendable).flush();
            }
      }

      @Override
      public void close() throws IOException {
            flush();
            if (appendable instanceof Closeable) {
                  ((Closeable) appendable).close();
            }
      }

}
```

---

Here is my own version, based on Marc's, that only uses `instanceof` only in the constructor, and a (Java 1.5) delta in `flush()` and `close()`. This is to avoid having to use any logic or reflection after object construction. This is also released as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aliteralmind/8494917): https://gist.github.com/aliteralmind/8494917

This class contains a demo, followed by two do-nothing deltas (one `Flushable`, one `Closeable`), the main function (`newWriterForAppendable(apbl)`), and then the adapter class itself.

```
   import  java.io.Closeable;
   import  java.io.Flushable;
   import  java.io.IOException;
   import  java.io.Writer;
/**
   <P>{@code java NewWriterForAppendable}.</P>
 **/
public class NewWriterForAppendable  {
   /**
      <P>Demonstrates {@code newWriterForAppendable(apbl)} for creating a new {@code Writer} that wraps around {@code System.out} (writes to the console).</P>
    **/
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      try  {
         NewWriterForAppendable.newWriterForAppendable(System.out).write("hello");
      }  catch(IOException iox)  {
         throw  new RuntimeException("WriterForAppendableXmpl", iox);
      }
   }
   /**
      <P>A {@code Flushable} whose {@code flush()} function does nothing. This is used by {@link #newWriterForAppendable(Appendable ap_bl) newWriterForAppendable}{@code (apbl)} as a (Java 1.5) delta.</P>

      @see  #newWriterForAppendable(Appendable) newWriterForAppendable(apbl)
    **/
   public static final Flushable FLUSHABLE_DO_NOTHING = new Flushable()  {
      public void flush()  {
      }
   };
   /**
      <P>A {@code Closeable} whose {@code close()} function does nothing. This is used by {@link #newWriterForAppendable(Appendable ap_bl) newWriterForAppendable}{@code (apbl)} as a (Java 1.5) delta.</P>

      @see  #newWriterForAppendable(Appendable) newWriterForAppendable(apbl)
    **/
   public static final Closeable CLOSEABLE_DO_NOTHING = new Closeable()  {
      public void close()  {
      }
   };
   /**
      <P>Creates a new {@code java.io.Writer} that wraps around a {@code java.lang.Appendable}. It properly {@link java.io.Writer#flush() flush}es and {@link java.io.Writer#close() close}s appendables that happened to also be {@link java.io.Flushable}s and/or {@link java.io.Closeable Closeable}s. This uses {@code instanceof} only in the constructor, and a delta in {@code flush()} and {@code close()}, which avoids having to use any logic or reflection after object construction.</P>

      <P>This function is released as a <A HREF="https://gist.github.com/aliteralmind/8494917">gist</A>, and is an example of the <A HREF="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Object_Adapter_pattern">Object Adapter pattern</A>. Thanks to <A HREF="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1211906/marc-baumbach">Marc Baumbach</A> on <A HREF="http://stackoverflow.com">{@code stackoverflow}</A> for the assistance. See (viewed 1/18/2014)
      <BR> &nbsp; &nbsp; <CODE><A HREF="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200421/how-to-wrap-a-java-lang-appendable-into-a-java-io-writer">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200421/how-to-wrap-a-java-lang-appendable-into-a-java-io-writer</A></CODE></P>

      @return  A new writer that uses an appendable to do its output.
      @see  #FLUSHABLE_DO_NOTHING
      @see  #CLOSEABLE_DO_NOTHING
    **/
   public static final Writer newWriterForAppendable(Appendable ap_bl)  {
      return  (new WFA(ap_bl));
   }
   private NewWriterForAppendable()  {
      throw  new IllegalStateException("constructor: Do not instantiate.");
   }
}
class WFA extends Writer  {
   private final Appendable apbl;
   private final Flushable  flbl;
   private final Closeable  clbl;
   public WFA(Appendable ap_bl)  {
      if(ap_bl == null)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("ap_bl");
      }
      apbl = ap_bl;

      //Avoids instanceof at every call to flush() and close()
      flbl = (Flushable)((ap_bl instanceof Flushable) ? ap_bl
         :  NewWriterForAppendable.FLUSHABLE_DO_NOTHING);
      clbl = (Closeable)((ap_bl instanceof Closeable) ? ap_bl
         :  NewWriterForAppendable.CLOSEABLE_DO_NOTHING);
   }
   @Override
   public void write(char[] a_c, int i_ndexStart, int i_ndexEndX) throws IOException {
      apbl.append(String.valueOf(a_c), i_ndexStart, i_ndexEndX);
   }
   @Override
   public Writer append(char c_c) throws IOException {
      apbl.append(c_c);
      return  this;
   }
   @Override
   public Writer append(CharSequence c_q) throws IOException {
      apbl.append(c_q);
      return  this;
   }
   @Override
   public Writer append(CharSequence c_q, int i_ndexStart, int i_ndexEndX) throws IOException  {
      apbl.append(c_q, i_ndexStart, i_ndexEndX);
      return  this;
   }
   @Override
   public void flush() throws IOException {
      flbl.flush();
   }
   @Override
   public void close() throws IOException {
      flush();
      clbl.close();
   }

}
```

Comment: Nitpick: For your impl of `write(char[], int, int)`, it is more efficient to use `apbl.append(String.valueOf(a_c, i_ndexStart, i_ndexEndX));` instead of `apbl.append(String.valueOf(a_c), i_ndexStart, i_ndexEndX);`?  I think this will reduce the number of bytes copied in cases when start & end are not `0` and `a_c.length`.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to use `CharBuffer.wrap(cbuf, off,  len)` instead of `String.valueOf(cbuf, off, len)`, because this creates a view for the existing `cbuf` and copies nothing at all to create a `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in a `Writer`, the `flush()` and `close()` are there to cleanup any additional writes that may not have been committed or sent to the stream. By simply redirecting all of the `write` methods directly to the `append` methods in the `Appendable` you won't have to worry about `flush()` and `close()` unless your `Appendable` implements `Closeable` and/or `Flushable`.

A good example is something like [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). When you are calling `write()` on that, it may not be sending all of the bytes to the final output/stream immediately. Some bytes may not be sent until you `flush()` or `close()` it. To be absolutely safe, I would test the wrapped `Appendable` if it is `Closeable` or `Flushable` in the corresponding method and cast it and perform the action as well.

This is a pretty standard design pattern called the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Here is what is likely a good implementation for this adapter: http://pastebin.com/GcsxqQxj

Comment: So you simply redirect all `write`s to `append`s, and create empty `close` and `flush` functions, and that's it!? If that's right, that's *nothing*. Thanks very much!

Comment: To be absolutely safe, in your `close` and `flush`, you could test the `Appendable` for whether it is `Closeable` or `Flusheable`, cast it and perform the appropriate action.

Comment: Ah. So it seems there is some reflection required after all. Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited to include a pastebin of an implementation which should work.

Comment: I've created my own version of your adapter class, which avoids having to use any logic or reflection after object construction. It's been added to the bottom of my original post.

Comment: I thought about that implementation as well. While `flush` and `close` are likely only to be called once, if `flush` is called multiple times, yours will have slightly better performance. Looks good!

Comment: I figured `close()` was called only once, but I thought `flush()` was called potentially a lot. Good to know.

Comment: If you're interested, yesterday I wrote this mega-answer-post on Functors (which I incorrectly called deltas), which uses this wrapper class as its example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22163940/2736496

Answer (score 0):

You can accept any `Appendable` and then check if it is a `Writer` through `instanceof`.  Then do a downcast and call that function that accepts only `Writer`.

example:

```
public void myMethod(Appendable app) throws InvalidAppendableException {

   if (app instanceof Writer) {
      someObj.thatMethod((Writer) app);
   } else {
      throw new InvalidAppendableException();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea in some cases. I would choose, however, to go with a non-reflection version.

Comment: Turns out that at least some reflection is required, so this is not as far off as I thought!

Answer (score 0):

Google's Guava has a simple utility to do this: [CharStreams.asWriter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#asWriter(java.lang.Appendable))

The implementation is not the fastest ([see](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2446)), if you want the best performance, you might want to look at spf4j [Streams.asWriter](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/src/main/java/org/spf4j/io/Streams.java#L117)