# Java - NavigableMap, which returns a functor, which returns a double

Tags: java, functor

I'm coming from C++ and I feel a little bit frustrated and confused. I was googling for help for a while and I still can't find an answer, so I am here.

How in Java can I implement a `NavigableMap<String, ?>` where at the question mark is an object which can be called with two arguments and then return a value.

I would like it to look like so:

```java
NavigableMap<String, SomeFunctorClass> container;

// I also don't know how to write a lambda thing in java, so it won't work.
// [](double a, double b) -> double { return a + b; } // in C++
container.put("add", (double a, double b) -> { return a + b; });

// Expected to be 10.
double result = container.get("add")(4, 6);
```

Comment: I think you want to use a BiFunction<Double, Double, Double>

Comment: It says that a type argument cannot be a primitive :\

Comment: Oh, you wrote `Double` not `double`. Give me a sec.

Comment: "I was googling for help for a while and I still can't find any answer" Really? I tried putting `java functor` into a search engine (not even Google!) and the first result I got was [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369460/help-with-understanding-a-function-object-or-functor-in-java). Does it not answer the question?

Comment: It still doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in java is a `BiFunction`:

```
NavigableMap<String, BiFunction<Double, Double, Double>> container;
container.put("add", (a, b) -> a + b);
```

Note that generics in Java cannot be primitive, so you should use the boxed versions (`Double` for `double`, `Integer` for `int` etc.)

If you need more than 2 parameters (for example a `TriFunction`), then you'll need to create your own interface since Java standard library doesn't offer more than that (it's not as extensible as C++).

As for the way of calling it:

```
// Expected to be 10.
double result = container.get("add").apply(4.0, 6.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing Java offers out of the box is probably a [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

You still won't be able to call it directly with `()` like you'd do on a C++ functor, but you can call its `apply` method:

```
NavigableMap<String, BiFunction<Double, Double, Double>> container = new TreeMap<>();
container.put("add", (a, b) -> a + b);
double result = container.get("add").apply(4.0, 6.0);
```